# Максимальное количество пользователей MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных, highload

Пытаюсь сделать прототип SaaS и есть пара вопросов по базам данных.

Для каждого пользователя saas будет создаваться своя база данных и свой пользователь. Отдельный пользователь базы нужен для безопасности данных остальных пользователей, так как SaaS предоставляет доступ к БД. Собственная база оптимальна по множеству критериев (распределённое по базам количество записей, быстрая индексация, поиск и тд), но не затронет ли "отдельный аккаунт в MySQL для каждого пользователя" производительность? По идее каждый пользователь это только запись в таблице mysql.user, но так ли это на практике? И будет ли MySQL справляться с, допустим, 1000 аккаунтов не хуже, чем с одним, при одинаковых нагрузках?

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: MySQL не умеет масштабироваться. Решения, конечно, есть, но они неизменно приводят к ручному отслеживанию ситуации и негласным молитвам о том, чтобы сегодня все не сломалось, а если у вас на забитом сервере кто-то из клиентов поползет по нагрузке вверх, то вы скорее всего потеряете и его, и тех, кого он задавит. Поэтому вместо того, чтобы запихивать всех в одну БД, рекомендую поднимать по инстансу mysql на каждого пользователя - правила игры значительно поменялись в последние пять лет, и любой менеджер контейнеров позволит вам это сделать.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Недавно сталкивался с контейнерами, но тут нужно будет поподробнее изучить тему.