# Как подключится к БД при регистрации нового пользователся?

Tags: php, mysql, регистрация, users

Хочу сделать регистрацию на сайте для пользователей, которые хотят составлять подборки новостей.

В мускуле у каждого пользователя будут таблицы куда заносятся понравившиеся ему новости, на основании которых будут составляться новые подборки.

Соответственно будет база данных в которой эти таблицы хранятся и для каждого пользователя будет свой мускул аккаунт с доступом к только его таблицам.
Так же будет главная таблица users, где будет основная информация по пользователям и их таблицам. Главная таблица наполняется данными в процессе регистрации.

Встает вопрос - как работать если в mysql ещё нет пользователя? Соответственно непонятно через кого подключаться к БД.

Я вижу вариант создать супер-пользователя mysql и всем подключаться через него при регистрации, вносить изменения в главную таблицу, и создавать нового пользователя с именем и паролем, указанным при регистрации.

Правильно ли я делаю?

Comment: сколько пользователей ожидаете, зачем эта архитектура с учеткой для каждого и своими таблицами? и в таком случае нужен не "супер пользователь", а учетка способная создать пользователя, создать таблицы и выдать ему права на эти таблицы.

Comment: 12 млн пользователей. Это задание для реферата по информатике  вместо ЕГЭ. По архитектуре - это моя задумка, мне показалось - так проще всего реализовать. Под суперпользователем я и имел ввиду такую учетку. Сразу вопрос - а как иначе это можно реализовать без учетки для каждого и своих таблиц? В моем случае пользователь проекта должен иметь возможность создать по таблице для каждой из категорий новостей. Есть варианты лучше, чем через БД?

Answer (score 0):

> В мускуле у каждого пользователя будут таблицы

Одна таблица на всех, не плодите сущностей.

> для каждого пользователя будет свой мускул аккаунт с доступом к только его таблицам.

Один пользователь базы данных (от которого unix-пользователь "www-data" будет работать с базой) на всех, права разграничивайте логикой приложения, не плодите сущностей.

Почитайте хотя бы минимум материала по SQL, там в примерах в основном с этого и начинается: пользователи, их статьи(контрольные работы, банковские счета,покупки в магазине и тд), разграничение прав, и все, что вы хотели знать, "но постеснялись спросить". 
 М. Грубер "Понимание SQL" - это просто must read, дальше ничего не делайте, пока его не прочитаете.

Comment: В моём случае SQL - Бен Форта. Не понял - ты рекомендуешь пользователям проекта работать под одним аккаунтом MySQL? Это же, вроде, самое зло? И часть логики же рекомендуют, наоборот, переносить в базы, т.к. в этом случае операции связанные с поиском и обработкой выполняются быстрее.

Comment: @O.O про "самое зло" это тебе сказал кто, или ты сам догадался?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613168/Максимальное-количество-пользователей-mysql      + сам догадался

Comment: Saas и публикация статей - это две большие разницы. Я не думаю, что публиковать статьи лучше под одним SQL-пользователем, я знаю, что публиковать статьи лучше под одним SQL-пользователем.

Comment: @O.O я не увидел по ссылке про "самое зло". В общем, не майся дурью, сделай одного пользователя и одну таблицу.